# Using Autofac scopes in WebApi2

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have went through most of the documentation, and I am still unsure about specific usage of dependency scopes.

When my request hits my controller, I usually can use dependencies of the controller (provided via Constructor Injection) and not worry myself about it much.

However, I am writing a `Delegating Handler`:

```
public class MyHandler: DelegatingHandler
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // I need IMyService here
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

I initially tried doing:

```
using(var scope = request.GetDependencyScope()){
    var service = scope.GetService(typeof(IMyService));
}
```

But that - while it works - seems to close the scope and prevent my Controller from even initializing correctly.

I could do:

```
{
      var requestScope = request.GetDependencyScope();
      var scope = requestScope.GetRequestLifetimeScope();

      var service = scope.Resolve<IMyService>();
      // use service
      return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

but will that not create resource leak? Will the `RequestLifetimeScope` be disposed of when the request finishes?

If you could provide me with a sample of correct, best-practices style basic DelegatingHandler using Autofac-resolved service, that would help me greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request-level dependency scope is created for you and disposed for you. Just get it (not inside a `using`) and resolve from it if you need to. Of course, make sure the Autofac middleware executes *before* your middleware so the scope can be created for you; and if that's the case, it'll clean up *after you*, too. Automatically.

Comment: I have tried the "I could do" code and it seems to work fine. If I understand you correctly, it is the correct way to resolve my service?

Comment: I would just GetDependencyScope and resolve from there, but yeah, if you have to do service location instead of DI, that's how. Note that's not Autofac specific - that's how Web API works.